# React and NodeJS Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cross-domain

I just started working with React and NodeJS. I created a server side NodeJS application and I am trying to send a HTTP request from my React application using Axios.

Server is running port 8080
`app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);`

My server controller:

```
const User = require('../models/Users');
const UserModel = new User();

exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.params.email;
    const password = req.params.password;
    const login = await UserModel.getUserLogin(email, password);
    res.status(202).send(JSON.stringify(login));
};
```

My React application is default `http://localhost:3000`

Here is where I call the server:

```
axios.get(Constants.SERVERURL + 'user/' + this.state.email + '/' + this.state.password,
    { crossDomain: true }
  ).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Constants.SERVERURL is `export const SERVERURL = "http://localhost:8080/";`

It returns error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/user/email@test.com/123. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)
```

How can I avoid the cross domain issue?

Thanks

Comment: *Have* you configured CORS on the (Express?) server? If not, have you looked up how to?

Comment: Do you mean in the NodeJS express application?

Comment: Yes, exactly. CORS requires the *server* to be configured correctly.

Comment: Thank you. It fixed my problem. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: I'd recommend just deleting this, there are plenty of CORS-related questions here already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `proxy` to `package.json`, as I remember that was most common solution to resolve CORS issue.

```json
{
   proxy: "localhost:8080"
}
```

The additional thing is about installing `cors` package and adding it as middleware to your express server, you can do that in the following way.

```js
const cors = reqiure("cors")

app.use(cors())
```